# Inserting values generated from query into a blank column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to count the number of points (stored in table2) that are found in each polygon of table 1. The query works but I have tried to alter it to add the valus generated to a blank column in table 1.

So far it only works by appending the results to the bottom of the table. Any help? To summarise I am trying to add values generated from this query into and add them into table1. At the moment the query inserts them into the blank column in table 1, but no matched against the ID, but appended at the bottom.

```
INSERT INTO table1(field3) 
SELECT COUNT(table2.id) AS count1
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
ON ST_Contains(table1.geom,table2.geom)
GROUP BY table1.id;
```

Comment: You need an `UPDATE` in order to populate the data into existing rows that match the `JOIN` criteria. Can you create a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15 with some sample data?

Comment: I am struggling to do this as it uses a PostGIS function that won't work in sqlfiddle. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're not missing anything - postgis isn't installed in the sqlfiddle databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only change I made here was to switch your left join to an inner join. In the case where a geometry in table1 contains no geometries in table2, the value of field3 will stay null, so you might want to start by doing an "update table1 set field3 = 0" first <strike>(it can turn out to be a bit faster doing that in two steps depending on how many features you have and how many points each geometry has)</strike>.

```
update table1 a
set field3 = b.count1
from
(
  SELECT table1.id,
         COUNT(table2.id) AS count1
  FROM table1
         JOIN table2
           ON ST_Contains(table1.geom,table2.geom)
  GROUP BY table1.id
) b
where a.id = b.id
```

Alternative:

```
update table1 a
set field3 = b.count1
from
(
  SELECT table1.id,
         COUNT(table2.id) AS count1
  FROM table1
         left JOIN table2
           ON ST_Contains(table1.geom,table2.geom)
  GROUP BY table1.id
) b
where a.id = b.id
```

Also, [this site](http://pgexercises.com/) just showed up on reddit this morning. I haven't spent much time digging through it but it looks promising as (yet another) resource for learning sql (in a postgres-specific environment).

Edit: I'm starting to doubt myself with regards to the two step approach that I first posted - I think it's almost entirely wrong about the performance, so I included an alternative query.